# Whitespace in C#

Tags: c#, whitespace

I'm a bit of a sucker for tidy code, so I like to have everything indented and flowing, if you know what I mean.

```
private void myFunc()
{
    while(true)
    {
        //do this
    }
}
```

etc. Now, I know that in a text file, the tab character or four spaces or whatever is actually stored in there, ready for the next time I open it.

If I go to compile this though, am I going to see any benefit in output filesize / compilation performance by not having tidy formatting and indentation, or does the compiler just ignore everything that isn't important?

Comment: C# is not Python or [Whitespace](http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace).

Comment: compiler doesn't care about white space unless it's syntactically significant

Comment: @BoltClock I don't believe I ever claimed it was. Python will throw an error with incorrect indentation, C# doesn't care. My question relates to the fact that those characters are within the source file, regardless of their syntactical requirement. You may wish to read the question again.

Comment: Why haven't you just compile 2 sources and compare the result binaries?

Comment: And even if that matter - it would always be better to keep sources in readable form and look for another, **more efficient** ways of improving your program performance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One of the compilation steps is known as [tokenization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokenization_(lexical_analysis)). This step removes all of the whitespace and comments from your code. As long as your code parses correctly, there's no difference between well formatted or poorly formatted code in terms of runtime speed.

Answer (score 3):

Your source code files would be smaller if you used only the bare minimum of white space, but the compiled file would remain the same. Favour readability of your source code.

Answer (score 1):

Spaces or tabs make no difference to the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

No difference in the compiled output, just the source

Answer (score 0):

The compiler converts your textual code into [CIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language), so all the formatting will be removed and it will make no difference to your dll's/exe's file size, so you can format it how ever you like.